# White-out / burned-out font

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, fonts

does anyone know how I can create such a white-out/ burned-out font like in the example attached? Either in Photoshop or Illustrator.

It looks like the text sits in front of a very bright light so that that edges of the text are burned out. At the same time some of the letters are merged together at the edges.

[image: see the edges of the text and the connections between the letters]

I would be very thankful for any tips!

Comment: Looks like a font by Neville Brody

Answer (score 2):

This is for Photoshop:

- Use a bold font, and decrease the tracking so the letters are bunched
  up quite close together.
- Convert the text layer into a Smart Object so you can still edit the
  text or tweak the settings later if necessary
- Add some Gaussian Blur
- Add a Levels Adjustment Layer as shown below

[image]

Comment: Yeah and then save a 70% quality JPG :)